# need to count how many student applied for particular course. and show this count in (UI)Frontend part

Tags: php, sql

i have project at university ,where one requirement is  student have to applied to the course posted by various institution.
for eg. if institute provide mechanical, chemical courses.and if number of student applied for mechanical course.
and my question is i need to count how many people applied for mechanical course. and show this count in (UI)Frontend part.
this is query i have written to retrieve students who applied for course.

```
$q="select * 
    from students 
    where student_id in (
        select applied_stdid 
        from applicants 
        where a_subjectid=".$_GET['id']." )";
```

and the code which i have written to find count and display is------>

```
<?php

$count=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))

    echo '<tr> <td width="10%">'.$count.'
        <td width="50%">'.$row['student_fnm'].'
        <td width="30%"><a href="'.$row['student_data'].'">Student Information</a>
';

$count++;
}

echo"count is".$count;
?>
```

above code is fine i m able to get the count but i have to show the count infront of course like mechanical--  20 student applied.i have to show this count in another(main page)page.the count which i m getting i have to show this in manin page

Comment: You're missing a `{` after `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))`. Is that a copying error?

Comment: @Barmer ,no actually there is no error in the code, actually the requirement is i have to show count in the front of the course name.

Comment: You have `}` after `$count++`, where is the matching `{`?

Comment: yes you are right copying error. may be i have not written the question clearly.mysql_num_rows is working fine for above code.but i have to show this count in another(main page)page.the count which i m getting i have to show this in manin page.

Comment: You can use session variables to pass data to another page.

Comment: //On above page
 `$_SESSION['count'] = $count;`

//On main page where i have to show count     @Barmar this what you are saying?
 `$count = $_SESSION['count'];`

Answer (score 0):

I Created a function for you it'll solve your issue. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
    //you can name this file as functions.php

    function fetchcount() {
        $sql = "SELECT * from applicants WHERE a_subjectid='1'";
        // eg. 1 for (mechanical) but you have to create individual function for all the courses
        $query = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
            $totlal=mysql_num_rows($query );
        }

        return $totlal;
    }

    ?>
```

In Your main file where you want to print the count. just do this:

```
require_once 'functions.php';
$res = fetchcount(); /
echo "count is".$res; // put it anywhere you want
```

Comment: actually on the page where a i want to display also contains one more query and another count like---->`$q="select * from course where course_owner_name='".$_SESSION['cnm']."'"; `    `<?php

$count=1;

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))

{
 
echo '<tr> <td width="10%">'.$count.'
 
<td width="50%"><a href="course_details.php?id='.$row['course_id'].'">'.$row['course_title'].'

<td width="10%"><a href="show.php?id='.$row['course_id'].'&nm='.$row['j_title'].'">show</a>

<td><a href="process_del_course.php?id='.$row['course_id'].'">delete</a></tr>';
      
   $count++;

}

?>`

Comment: `a_subjectid` column is in the applicants table and this column represent id of course. and from the above code you have shown it in student table. applicants table containd three column  id student_id a_subjectid(posted course id)

Comment: ok you must have the column  where you store your info like mechanical,chemical etc.. Or id for the courses like 1 for (mechanical) and 2 for (chemical ) you can match with that. i made the function where you don't need any kind of session.. this gives the exact count

Comment: @itsoftware i have edited the code try to implement now in the select query you can change the table or column name to match the result as you want

Comment: thanks for your efforts, the query` $sql = "SELECT * from applicants WHERE a_subjectid='1'";` here you are using id =1 in query it self instead what i m trying `$q="select applied_stdid  from applicants where a_subjectid=".$_GET['id']." ";`

Comment: @itsoftware as you know get method is not secure to show such kind of data..if still you want to go for this it's your wish i gave a secure way. anyways thanks.

Comment: It is not a good idea to select * - especialyl not if you dont need all rows. In the particular case not selecting all but using a databse count(*) function greatly reduces network traffic.